# Pyinstaller compiled file error

Tags: python-2.7, shell, exe, pyinstaller, statsmodels

I had used created a GUI by wxpython to run stats model using statsmodels SARIMAX(). I put all five scripts in one file and tried to use

```
pyinstaller --onedir <mainscript.py>
```

to create compiled application.

After the pyinstaller process completed, I ran the generated application in dist file but it gave this error:

```
c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-dm6yoc\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:389:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "envs\conda_env1\myApp\mainscript.py", line 2, in <module>
File "c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-dm6yoc\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", 
line 389, in load_module
File "envs\conda_env1\myApp\my_algorithm.py", line 3, in <module>
File "c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-builddm6yoc\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", 
line 389, in load_module
File "site-packages\statsmodels\api.py", line 22, in <module>
File "c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-builddm6yoc\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", 
line 389, in load_module
File "site-packages\statsmodels\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tools.sm_exceptions
Failed to execute script mainscript
```

I used python2.7 in Windows8 to create the GUI and statsmodel algorithm in conda environment but the pyinstaller was done by pip install. I wonder if this is what caused the error?? Any advise or link to associated discussion would be appreciated!! (I don't even know which topics this problem falls into ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this problem seems to be that the execution file does not recognize relative import in statsmodels (and other) libraries I used.
The problem solved when I modified the relative import in every imports.
For example:

```
form .tools import sm_exceptions
```

to

```
form statsmodels.tools import sm_exceptions
```

Answer (score 0):

> No module named tools.sm_exceptions

Looks like you have a missing module called "tools.sm_exceptions"

Comment: I can run the mainscript without any problem in Pycharm though..I wonder what is the path pyinstaller use to compile the script?